# How to get enum element from index

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, indexing

I have a select in which I do a "group by". One of the columns is an enum, and I want to select the biggest value for each group (i.e the one with the largest index in the enum). I can do

```
select MAX(enum_column+0) as enum_index
```

to get the the largest index in the group, but how can I turn the enum index back to the enum item?

---

Example:
Say I have a table "soldiers" with three columns:

```
"id" - soldier's ID
"name" is the soldier's first name (a varchar field).
"rank" is the soldier's rank, and it is an enum: 
{'private','sergent'...,'lieutenant' etc.}
```

Now suppose I want to find for each first name, the the highest rank a person with that name has.
I can do:

```
select MAX(rank+0) as enum_index,name from soldiers group by name
```

But that will give me the index of the max element in the enum field, and not the name of the element. I.e it will give me:

```
1 | john
2 | bob
```

where I want

```
'private' | john
'sergent' | bob
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: You're missing how rank is a number that changes into a string/varchar rank_name value.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, but if you mean I didn't explain how ran changes from string to int, it is because it's an ENUM type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following

```
CREATE TABLE ranks
SELECT DISTINCT rank+0 as id, CONCAT('',rank) as rank
FROM soldiers
```

Then join the data with the soldiers table. Notice it will give you only the ranks actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTR( MAX(CONCAT(0+column, column)), 2)
```

The concat will generate items like `0private` or `1sergeant`; these will be sorted as strings when taking the `MAX`. In this case this is the same as sorting by enum order. Finally the initial digit is removed by the `substr`.

If you have more than 10 items in your enum you'll have to format the numeric value with leading digits and remove the additional digits in the `substr` call.